# simple_form is blank for sign-in but formatted properly for sign-up

Tags: ruby, simple-form

I am working through adding simple_form formatting to simple sign-in and sign-up forms.

While the sign-up form is formatting properly - the sign-in form has no inputs?

Sign-in form

[image]

My code is available on github ([here](https://github.com/jrlundberg/omrails)) with the most recent version pushed which includes this error. Any ideas for a newbie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<%` with `<%=` next to the `f.input` statement.

```
    <h2>Sign in</h2>

    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :password %>
      <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```